# Counting specific word occurrences between 2 data frames in R with a group_by needed

Tags: r, dataframe, text-mining, matching

I have two data frames in R, the first one (named Words) is composed by a single columns of words :

| Words |
| --- |
| Hello |
| Building |
| School |
| Hospital |
| Doctors |

The second is a big dataset presented like this :

| id | description |
| --- | --- |
| 382 | Building a school |
| 787 | Hiring doctors for the new hospital and teachers for the school |

Then, i'd like to group by ID and to obtain the following results

| id | description | Match |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 382 | Building a school | 2 |
| 787 | Hiring doctors for the new hospital and teachers for the school | 3 |

Here is what i tried

```
library(stringr)

df <- df %>% group_by(df$id)

getCount <- function(data,keyword)
{
  wcount <- str_count(df$description, keyword)
  return(data.frame(data,wcount))
}

gCount(df$description,Words)
```

(I also tried by converting the Words dataset to a list)

As well as :

```
df <- df %>% group_by(df$id)
table(df$description)

df$match <- df[df$description %in% Words$Words,]
table(df$match)
```

And finally

```
Words.list <- setNames(split(Words, seq(nrow(Words))), rownames(Words))
description <- subset(df, select = c("description","id"))
description <- description %>% group_by(description$id)
description.list <- setNames(split(description, seq(nrow(description))), rownames(description))

str_to_search = Words.list
str_to_count = description.list

lengths(regmatches(str_to_search, gregexpr(str_to_count, str_to_search, fixed = TRUE)))
```

However i only have weird error messages that i don't understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
library(stringr)
library(purrr)

words <- c("Hello", "Building", "School", "Hospital", "Doctors") %>%
  str_to_lower()
descriptions <- c("Building a school", "Hiring doctors for the new hospital and teachers for the school") 

df_descriptions <- data.frame(description = descriptions) %>%
    mutate(Match = map_int(str_to_lower(description), ~str_count(.x, words) %>% sum()))
```

**edit**

```
df_descriptions <- data.frame(description = descriptions) %>%
  mutate(
    Match = str_to_lower(description) %>%
      str_split(" ") %>%
      map_int(~sum(.x %in% words))
  )
```

Comment: It worked on this example but `str_count` might not be best choice. For example if you have word schools it will get detected because school is part of it. If you want to avoid partial word matching check edit.